# the content function is ignoring more tag

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm doing "page of post" in twenty eleven theme. Problem is that the_content function ignores more tag and show the whole post. It work just fine in index page. 
My code:

```
    /*
    Template Name: Page Of Posts
    */
    ?>
     <?php get_header(); ?>
     <div id="primary">
     <div id="content" role="main">
     <?php
      $args= array(
  'category_name' => '');
      query_posts($args);
        if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>               
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </article><!-- #post-0 -->

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you list a file you are requesting with `get_template_part('content', get_post_format() )` it should be in the theme folder named like content-gallery.php(or any other post_format).

Anyway, you can try the good old:

```
<?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>
```

Place it before the call for the content.